# Wpf DataTemplate to draw multiple lines

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, datatemplate

I have the need to draw multiple lines with a single DataTemplate like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MultilineDataTemplate">
<Line X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" X2="{Binding X2}" Y2="{Binding Y2}" Fill="Red"
StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Where X1,Y1,X2,Y2 are arrays of coordinates.

I wonder if it is possible to use that DataTemplate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IValueConverter that converts your multiple arrays into a list of bindable objects.

```
public class ArrayCoordinateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ViewModelClassHere viewModel = (value as ViewModelClassHere);

        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            // Assuming that X1 will always have cooresponding elements in X2, Y1, Y2;
            var enumerable = viewModel .X1.Select((x, i) => new
            {
                X1 = x, 
                X2 = viewModel.X2[i], 
                Y1 = viewModel.Y1[i], 
                Y2 = viewModel.Y2[i]
            });

            return  enumerable;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource arrayCoordinateConverter}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line X1="{Binding X1}"
                    Y1="{Binding Y1}"
                    X2="{Binding X2}"
                    Y2="{Binding Y2}"
                    Fill="Red"
                    StrokeThickness="2"
                    Stroke="Black" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```